conformal maps of S2 to compact topologically equivalent region in R3?
How do I conformally, compactly map the unit sphere in $R^3$?
I know that if I have a compact, simply connected region of the plane, $R^2$, I can create a conformal map onto a new region in the same plane just by treating it as the complex plane and mapping a point $z$ to a point $f(z)$, with $\partial_{\bar{z}} f = 0$.
Now suppose I have the unit sphere, consisting of the points $\mathbf{r}^2 = 1$, and I wish to map these points to some new points $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})$ in $R^3$ conformally, meaning that the angles between vectors in the tangent plane are preserved. I also wish that the result be compact, which rules out stereographic projection.
What such maps exist? I know translation, rotation, dilation and the special conformal transformation all work, but I assume there is a much broader class of maps.

Are you fixing a smooth, compact surface $S$ homeomorphic to a sphere and asking for all conformal $f$ from $S^2$ to $S$, or is $S$ also arbitrary (but smooth and homeomorphic to $S^2$)?

Are you familiar with the Uniformization Theorem for Riemannian metrics on surfaces diffeomorphic to the sphere?

Andrew D. Hwang, I guess I'm letting $S$ be arbitrary in $R^3$ but smooth and homeomorphic to $S^2$. But I'd also be interested to know of any functions whatsoever that map to any surfaces whatsoever, beyond those I already mentioned.

Moishe Kohan, I wasn't familiar with the Uniformization Theorem. Does that mean that there should be a way to smoothly deform the sphere conformally into any other shape, such as a barbell-shaped blob? If so, that's interesting but I'm still interested in how to find functions that do that.

"Deform" is too imprecise. The correct terminology is "map to conformally." Finding explicit maps is hard, it amounts to solving some nonlinear PDE, but there is probably a literature on doing this numerically.
